# Adding hidden field to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on a UITableView inside a UIViewControlller and I would like to add a new cell to a row, but in a way that the only thing showing on the table would be the user defined name, but hidden data (such as a hyperlink) would be retained too. The purpose is to open such hyperlink when pressing the relative button.

I'm using

```
[dataSource addObject:UserDefineddName];
```

and this adds the name to the row, but how can I add the data too, without displaying it?

I have labels and a button set up in IB and I was thinking that perhaps the link could be assigned to a hidden label, but it's not clear to me how to do it.

Please advise!
Many thanks

Comment: How would the user access the hidden data? and where do you want the  data to show?

Comment: If you feel like my answer was satisfactory, please mark it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for your data with two properties, `name` and `url`. Then simply fill your data source with instances of this class instead of simply strings. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do something like this:

```
titleLabel.text = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].name;
```